# MenuFlyout for Items in GridView in Windows 8.1 HubApp

Tags: windows, xaml, gridview, windows-8.1

I have Windows 8.1 Hub App that will eventually be released for tablets. I want to add MenuFlyout to GridView. So if I right click or hold then flyout will display. I've gone through several videos, tutorials etc. but none of them relates to `GridView`. Only for ListView on WindowsPhone. So none of them show how I should approach.

Is it possible? How I should deal with it?

**HubSection**

This is how my `Hubsection` with `GridView` looks like.

```
<HubSection x:Name="CalcButtons" x:Uid="calculator" Header="{Binding Res.calc2Header, Source={StaticResource SharedStrings}}">
    <DataTemplate>
        <GridView
            ItemsSource="{Binding}"
            AutomationProperties.AutomationId="ItemGridView"
            AutomationProperties.Name="Items In Group"
            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource StandardCalcButton}"
            SelectionMode="None"
            IsItemClickEnabled="True" Margin="0,0,0,0" ItemClick="GridView_ItemClick">
            <GridView.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <ItemsWrapGrid/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </GridView.ItemsPanel>
        </GridView>
    </DataTemplate>
</HubSection>
```

**StandardCalcButton**

I've created `MenuFlayout` as resource in App.xaml and attached it to `GridViewItem` DataTemplate. So it looks like this.

```
<MenuFlyout x:Key="CalcFlyout">
    <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Test1"/>
    <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Test2"/>
</MenuFlyout>

<DataTemplate x:Key="StandardCalcButton" >
    <Grid Height="180" Width="180" Margin="5,5,5,5"  FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout="{StaticResource CalcFlyout}" >
        <Border Height="180" Background="{StaticResource AppYellow}">
            <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,0,0,0">
                <Image Source="{Binding ImagePath}" AutomationProperties.Name="{Binding Title}" Height="130" Width="180"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" Style="{StaticResource TitleTextBlockStyle}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" TextLineBounds="Tight" TextAlignment="Center"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Subtitle}" Style="{StaticResource BodyTextBlockStyle}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" TextLineBounds="Tight" LineStackingStrategy="BlockLineHeight" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" TextAlignment="Center" />
            </StackPanel>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

This is how I want to make Flyout to open in `GridView_ItemClicked`

```
private void GridView_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e){
    FrameworkElement senderElement = e.ClickedItem as FrameworkElement;
    if (senderElement == null)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("null");
        return;
    } else
    {
        FlyoutBase flyoutBase = FlyoutBase.GetAttachedFlyout(senderElement);
        flyoutBase.ShowAt(senderElement);
    }
}
```

''ClickedItem'' is object which I deliver in ''GridView.DataContext'' so there is no way that it will be castable to FrameworkElement.

Now I'm stuck. I'll be thankful for any guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
private void GridView_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {

        var gridViewItemsControl = sender as ItemsControl;
        var clickedItemContainer = gridViewItemsControl.ContainerFromItem(e.ClickedItem);

        Debug.WriteLine(clickedItemContainer);

        var clickedGridViewItem = clickedItemContainer as GridViewItem;
        var clickedItemGrid = clickedGridViewItem.ContentTemplateRoot as Grid;

        FlyoutBase flyoutBase = FlyoutBase.GetAttachedFlyout(clickedItemGrid);
        flyoutBase.ShowAt(clickedItemGrid);

    }
```

Hope i helps! :)